# I cannot open two PyCharm instance on two VNC Window(or Server)

Tags: pycharm, vnc

I create two vncserver by command "`vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 :1`"(VNC#1) and "`vncserver -geometry 1920x1080 :2`"(VNC#2). Then I open the PyCharm application on VNC(#1) terminal by command "`pycharm ~/Project1`". This applaction display on the VNC(#1), correctly. But, when I open another pycharm applaction on the VNC(#2) terminal by command "`pycharm ~/Project2`". The wired thing comming : this PyCharm application display on the VNC(#1) but VNC(#2). There are nothing on VNC(#2) window.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this kind of problem by following strategy:

On VNC#1(virtual desktop #1), I run PyCharm Community Version.

On VNC#2(virtual desktop #2), I run PyCharm Professional Version.

[Result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlahi.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify your question and the provided answer?